# How can I implement access restrictions to a Spring controller API based on a user's roles, and send a message back to the user?

Tags: javascript, spring, authentication, datatable

I have implemented a DataTable configuration featuring a delete button within each row. Nevertheless, the functionality of the delete button is restricted to users with specific roles, such as "ADMIN." Users lacking the "ADMIN" or "EDITOR" role will encounter a prompt notifying them of their unauthorized access when attempting to use the delete button.

This is the button, it's being rendered in one of my DataTable columns:

```
<form style="display:inline !important;" action="/admin/delete/" method="post" onsubmit="return confirm('Do you really want to delete employee ${row.id} ?');">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="${row.id}" />
<button class="form-command btn btn-danger btn-sm" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></button>
</form>`;
```

This is the delete API in the controller class:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole({'ROLE_ADMIN', 'ROLE_EDITOR'})")
    @DeleteMapping("delete")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    void delete(@RequestBody Integer id) {
        deleteEntity(id);
    }
```

The @PreAuthorize annotation is supposed to check the roles of the authenticated user and if they aren't authorized deny them. The thing is I want to send a message to the front-end user to tell them that they don't have permission to delete a row.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#tableID').DataTable({
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": {
            "url": "api-endpoint",
            "type": "POST",
            'beforeSend': function (xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader(csrfHeader, csrfToken);
            },
            'data': function (d) {
                d.search.value = d.search.value || '';
                d.columns[2]['search']['value'] = d.columns[2]['search']['value'] || '';
                d.columns[3]['search']['value'] = d.columns[3]['search']['value'] || '';
                d.columns[4]['search']['value'] = d.columns[4]['search']['value'] || '';
            },
        },
        "columns": [
            // ... (other columns remain unchanged)
        {
                    "data": null,
                    "render": function (data, type, row) {
                        let dropdownMenu = ``;
                        let deleteForm = `
                        <form style="display:inline !important;" action="/admin/delete/" method="post" onsubmit="return confirm('Do you really want to delete employee ${row.id} ?');">
                            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="${row.id}" />
                            <button class="form-command btn btn-danger btn-sm" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></button>
                        </form>`;

                        return dropdownMenu + "<br/>" + deleteForm;
                    },
                    "orderable": false
                }
            
        ],
        initComplete: function () {
            // ... (unchanged)
        }
    });
});
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by implementing a `GlobalExceptionHandler`. Below is an example code snippet:

```java
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(AccessDeniedException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<ProblemDetail> handleAccessDeniedException(AccessDeniedException e) {
        ProblemDetail problemDetail = ProblemDetail.forStatusAndDetail(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED, e.getMessage());
        problemDetail.setTitle("Requested Resource is UNAUTHORIZED");
        return new ResponseEntity<>(problemDetail, HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
    }

}
```

This code defines a `GlobalExceptionHandler` using the `@ControllerAdvice` annotation. It includes a specific exception handling method for `AccessDeniedException` using the `@ExceptionHandler` annotation. The method constructs a `ProblemDetail` object with details about the unauthorized access and returns it in a `ResponseEntity` with a `401 (UNAUTHORIZED)` status.

The response generated by this code will resemble the following JSON structure:

```json
{
  "type": "about:blank",
  "title": "Requested Resource is UNAUTHORIZED",
  "status": 401,
  "detail": "Access Denied",
  "instance": "/api/secured"
}
```